# Can't Skype one particular contact any more

Tags: skype

I use Skype to contact only 2 people.  With one there has never been a problem...in the last few weeks, the 2nd person and I are no longer able to Skype each other at all, but for months prior to this, we had no problems either.
One of us rings...the other hears the call, clicks to answer...but the call doesn't seem to come / go through.  It happens in both directions...me to friend or friend to me.  Same thing with sending sms messages...they are typed, press send,appear to go through but the other person doesnt recieve them...

Comment: Can the other person still skype with others? It sounds like the problem is on the other end.

Comment: Can you give some more information on your issue.

Comment: Have you tried https://web.skype.com in a browser? Try it one end at a time, to see where the problem is.